# Sequelize: Transaction issues when running a query simultaneously

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

**Problem:**

Everytime a simultaneous request to my route endpoint which runs an INSERT statement with a transaction, (ex: client1 and client2 making a request to my POST /payment route), it throws this error:

`rollback has been called on this transaction(5459992f-d69b-4c7d-8b32-824ded273de6), you can no longer use it.`

I have this route POST /payment

```
router
    .route('/v1/payment')
    .post(controller.payBill);
```

```
async payBill(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const transaction = await DB.MAINDB.transaction();
        let isCommitted = false;

        try {
            const { originalUrl, method, requestor, body } = req;

            logger.info(`ORIGIN: ${req.get('origin')}`);

            const { account_no } = req.body;
            let consumer = null;

            try {
                consumer = await getConsumerBalance(account_no);
            } catch (err) {
                logger.error(err);
                return next(err);
            }
            
            // WITH TRANSACTION
            const newData = await DB.MAINDB.models.Payment.create({
                ...somedata
                amount_paid: d.payment_amount,
            }, { transaction });

            await DB.MAINDB.models.PaymentLog.create({
                ...somedata
                payment_amount: d.payment_amount,
            }, { transaction });

            await transaction.commit();
            isCommitted = true;

            res.send({ 
                success: true, 
                timestamp: dayjsDate.unix(),
                payment_date: d.payment_date,
                payment_time: d.payment_time,
                payment_amount: d.payment_amount,
                total_bill: consumer.total_bill,
                outstanding_bill: 0
            });
        } catch (err) {
             if (!isCommitted) {
                await transaction.rollback();
                // This will throw the error
             }
          
            logger.error(err);
            next(err);
        }
    }
```

This is the DB class

```
const DBOption = {
    dialect: 'mysql' as Dialect,
    dialectOptions: {
        connectTimeout: 60000,
    },
    port: 4000,
    logging: false,
    pool: {
        max: 50,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 60000,
        idle: 10000
    },
    retry: {
        match: [/Deadlock/i],
        max: 3, // Maximum rety 3 times
        backoffBase: 1000, // Initial backoff duration in ms. Default: 100,
        backoffExponent: 1.5, // Exponent to increase backoff each try. Default: 1.1
    },
}

class DBClass {
    public MAINDB: DBProp;

    constructor() {
       this.MAINDB = new Sequelize('testdb', 'root', 'root',
            { host: 'localhost', ...DBOption  }
        );

        this.initiate();
    }

    initiate() {
        glob
            .sync(`*.ts`, { cwd: `${__dirname}/../models/` })
            .map((filename: string) => {
                return {
                    file: require(`${__dirname}/../models/${filename}`),
                    name: path.basename(filename, env === 'development' ? '.ts' : '.js')
                };
            })
            .forEach(model => {
                this.MAINDB.models[model.name] = model.file.default(this.MAINDB);
            });

        associate(this.MAINDB);

    }
}

export const DB = new DBClass();
```

Simultaneous request to the `/payment` route will only accept the first request and will fail the other client and will throw this error `rollback has been called on this transaction(5459992f-d69b-4c7d-8b32-824ded273de6), you can no longer use it.`

How do I make a distinct transaction for every request? Please enlighten me.

Comment: what is `transactionBCMS`?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. It's supposed to be ```transaction``` as defined from above.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the issue but try without `if (!isCommitted)` check? I am wondering if `commit()` throws an error, this will clean up the connection and `isCommitted` is still `false` and tries to `rollback` on the already cleaned up transaction.

Comment: Do you have stacktrace? What line caused the error?